# C# - How to change value for property using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I used reflection and found the **IsSelected** property of the Simulate tab:

[image]

Because there is no dll (i think VM is Virtual Machine), so could not:

```
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Gui.Common.VM.BaseVM
```

or

```
using Autodesk.Navisworks.Timeliner.VM
```

In this context, has 4 tab *TasksTabVM*, *DataSourcesTabVM*, *ConfigureTabVM*, *SimulateTabVM*
How do I determine the「IsSelected」property of each tab?

Is there a way to change the value of property **IsSelected** using reflection?

Any tips on these will be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off the top of my head, `tabs.GetType().GetProperty("IsSelected").SetValue(tabs, true);`

Comment: By the way, VM is more likely to mean "view model" in this context.

Comment: @JonathonChase In this context, has 4 tab TasksTabVM, DataSourcesTabVM, ConfigureTabVM, SimulateTabVM
How do I determine the「IsSelected」property of each tab?
DavidG Thank you!

Comment: iterate over tabs. `foreach(var tab in tabs) Console.WriteLine(tab.GetType().GetProperty("IsSelected").GetValue(tab));`

Comment: Because cannot using dll, use foreach() will have the error:
*The foreach statement can not be used for variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain the public definition of 'GetEnumerator'.*

Comment: You can cast it to IEnumerable.

Comment: @JonathonChase it worked fine. Thank you very much!!! +2